# Twitter Bot Posting Data from Mysql Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, bots

I want to make a twitter bot which posts data (news) from a mysql database just for an experiment.

I have searched a lot of places on the internet and this website, but a lot of the information is not about php, but using other programming languages.

That is why I want to ask somebody who has experience in twitter bots, mysql or php.

My database php is called ytable.php and I have columns called Title, Pubdate and Link.

This is the general knowledge I have for the moment.

```
require(ytable.php);
$consumerKey       = 'aa';
$consumerSecret    = 'bb';
$accessToken       = 'cc';
$accessTokenSecret = 'dd';
$oAuth = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
```

This is all the knowledge I have so far.
I want to pull data from the database by row like:

```
$Twitter = News:$Title Check it out here:$Link $Pubdate;
```

Something along those lines.

Even if you have no knowledge about bots, can you explain to how to pull data from  mysql database/table or link me a website to inform me.